# Azure Application Insights - Standard Test with Auth

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Wanting to setup a standard test that utilizes user login. Tried `userinfo` and `authorization` headers with `user:password`, but neither appears to work as expected.

Couldn't find guidance anywhere else on this.

Comment: You mean an availability test?

Comment: Yeah, standard availability test

Comment: Could you provide some more information what you tried ?